# Advices fo starting a video game design career

Tags: game-design, game-industry

I'm 24 and have a passion for video games and game-design. I've decided I want to design video games as my career.

I have no experience with designing video games or coding but I'm interested and willing to learn. I want a job at any level but what would I need to land a job?

I have no college experience and I have no money. What is a cheap school, or do I really need to go to school for this, or can I learn on my own? Is it possible to do this with no money? I'm literally broke but I want this so bad I feel like its the only career I'll enjoy.

I want to call up company's and ask them what they are looking for in someone they want to hire, is that a good idea?

Also I don't know the history of video game design and I don't want to sound like a dummy when someone says something about this field or talks about a famous designer and I have no idea who they're talking about. So what is key info when it comes to this field and where should I find it?

Hopefully some of you guys and girls can help me out: I know in the future I will create something everyone will enjoy and you guys will remember when you gave me advice and I will always remember you guys for helping me. I'm gifted I know I am and I want to share my gift with the rest of the world by making games that change the Industry. Help me out please.

Comment: This might be too broad to be answered, and I wouldn't be suprised this gets closed for this very reason. I won't personally vote for this as this calls for a good, detailed, answer. Just please, next time, try to format your question a bit better, a single block paragraph all in bold isn't gonna bring you more attention.

Comment: Voting to close. This is unanswerable. If you want to get started in making games, then start making games. Become skilled in something, become valuable to a company. It's not like applying for a random desk job. You need to contribute a lot to the development of any given project. Nowadays there's no cost barrier to learning how to make games, so you've got no excuse. Hit the books.

Comment: This question is far too discussion oriented, so it is not a fit for our Q&A site. Please ask it on a discussion forum like gamedev.net or Reddit. Also read [this article](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/game-programming/how-do-i-make-games-a-path-to-game-development-r892) about how to start making games.

Answer (score 4):

You said "*I have no experience with designing video games or coding*", but you haven't said what you're able to do... I hope you have at least a very deep IT knowledge.
To do career in videogame-industry is very hard, most of the times you should start with an indie game (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indie_game). If you gain success with that you can then report it in your CV or you can start your own business.

Anyway, if you need money you should work in a different industry and try to develop your game in your free time.

Answer (score 3):

In case you haven't checked it out yet, this is a site that is very good to read when a person has questions like yours:

http://sloperama.com/advice.html